# import Line from react-chartjs-2 from the wrong place

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to switch the position of the yAxes in my line graph to the right.
It seems that the library of Line in this link https://codesandbox.io/s/5z3ss, is different from mine: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Props & React.RefAttributes>. In that library type of Line is mandatory and the position does not change.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify your code as below to have the yAxis on the rught side:

```
     <Line 
         data={data} 
         options= {
          {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
                ticks: {
                 beginAtZero: true
                }
               }]
            }
          }
         }
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, `react-chartjs-2` uses `chart.js`, it just wrap in React component and pass all option down.
The options you needs to change yAxes to the right can be found [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/_common.html)

Updated code:

```js
const options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        position: "right"
      }
    ]
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Line data={data} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: the problem is that this code doesnt work I think because there is a problem with my Import. Also with this code it makes an error because I have to set the tyep

Comment: @oriporia i just forked you codesanbox, no issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-line-chart-example-forked-vwz95?file=/src/App.js   are you using typescript in your project ?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. need to be version 2.11.2 of react-chartjs-2, thank you